# Why was Doral opposing Roslin?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the show opener, after the Cylon attack happens, Laura Roslin tries to take charge on the ship she is on. Doral objects, and he later discusses it with Lee Adama. Might this be because he was trying to prevent some semblance of order taking hold, or was he maybe trying to position himself or another to take charge?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes. This Doral is amongst the Cylons who want the genocide of humanity. This is much before the Cylons vote to give humanity a chance, ending their all out attacks for alternative motives. Doral is doing everything he can to ensure that the humans are in-fighting so that the Cylons can get an upper hand.